# How to test uploadfile in django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have an uploadform and I want to test it. But there is a problem.

```
def test_if_can_upload_file(self):
    with open('app_blog/tests/test.txt') as file:
        self.client.post(reverse('csv_blog'), {'attachment': file})
        test_file = file.read()
        self.assertEqual(test_file, 'test file')
```

When I test it, there is an error:

```
self.assertEqual(test_file, 'test file')
AssertionError: '' != 'test file'
+ test file
```

Why is my file shown like it is empty? Actually it is not empty.Or maybe I test my form in a wrong way?

form

```
class UploadBlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = 'file',
```

view

```
def upload_blog(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        upload_file_form = UploadBlogForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if upload_file_form.is_valid():
            blog_file = upload_file_form.cleaned_data['file'].read()
            blog_str = blog_file.decode('utf-8').split('\n')
            csv_reader = reader(blog_str, delimiter=":::", quotechar='"')
```

Comment: The upload will already exhaust the file handler.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can you explain please? I don't understand your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `self.client.post(…)` will already *exhaust* the file handler and read the entire content of the file, this thus means that when you call `file.read()`, the cursor already moved to the end of the file, and thus returns an empty string.

You should reopen the file and read the file from the beginning, so:

```
def test_if_can_upload_file(self):
    with open('app_blog/tests/test.txt') as file:
        self.client.post(reverse('csv_blog'), {'attachment': file})
    with open('app_blog/tests/test.txt') as file:
        test_file = file.read()
        self.assertEqual(test_file, 'test file')
```